# Rational versus intelligent agents

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Question about "Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach by Russell and Norvig"

I have issue to distinguish clearly between intelligent and rational agent presented by Norvig and Russel. What I understand is that rational agent think and act like human but not intelligent agent. Thus, Russel present 4 types of intelligents agents
– Simple reflex agents
– Model-based reflex agents
– Goal-based agents
– Utility-based agents

My question is : could Goal-based agents be a rational agents at the same time ? Does this concept limite intelligence to just human intelligence ? Some paper do not make distinction between these two terms.

Answer (score 1):

Before I go straight to your question, we have to get a clear picture of these two terms that might seem confusing;

1.rationality(an agent is able to perform given task x after analysing y,that is right fit for x).

2.intelligence.(an agent is able to perform given task x after analysing y inline with reasoning ie..why x?....).

could Goal-based agents be a rational agents at the same time ?
Basing on the above two hints,the answer is yes.

Does this concept limit intelligence to just human intelligence ?
According to artificial intelligence research,so far,we haven't reached at the level of human intelligence (artificial general intelligence).

Hope this can give you some insights.